# Java script Web-Cam

Tags: c#, asp.net, byte, webcam, src

I have a JavaScript that takes a image and puts it in image attribute `src` as `data:image/png;base64,` my image tag is `<img  id="photo"  runat="server" src="" />` i made it `runat="server"` so i could take it to the code behind so i want the `src` of it to convert it to Byte[] so i could take it to database but when i say `Photo.Src` it shows empty it wont show the data on the front browser it shows

[image: It shows it has src]
even if i try to `File.ReadAllBytes(Photo);`  it says empty URL is not legal error.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you have and what you trying to achieve, but it may be useful for you to know that `img` tag does not post back anything to server (similar to other once like `div` and `head`).

Comment: There i removed the Space in between Java Script sorry about that and also how do i take that image that's inside the img tag and get its bytes. It shows the image using Base64 string value. I want that string value to convert into bytes on the code behind

Comment: @user7389750 You can get the content image file in JavaScript and then send it via Post request directly.

Answer (score 0):

The `image/file` should be at server in order to change the `src` attribute of `img` tag. The `src` attribute expects `URL` of the image. You cannot simply set the content of image as `src`.

This suggests that you need to transfer `image` to server first. There are various ways using AJax/JQuery etc.

The simplest example in ASP .net as:

```
<form id="YourForm" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="yourImageFile" name="yourImageFile" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonUpload" OnClick="fileUpload" Text="Send Image" />
</form>
```

You can get the content at `Server` as:

```
protected void fileUpload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the file here
    HttpPostedFile fileImage = Request.Files["yourImageFile"];

    //You can do whatever you want with fileImage object. Like
    BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(fileImage.InputStream);
    byte[] binaryData = bReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

    //Convert to Base64
    String imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData);
}
```

Comment: I didnt quiet understand i want the Base64 string of that img tag on the server side to convert into bytes and save into database.

Comment: @user7389750 You got the file in your code behind. Read binary content of file and convert that to Base64. Let me edit answer to demonstrate it.

Comment: I think you miss Understood i dont need to upload the image its showing me upload the image and also it sent nothing back using that method i am trying to take the image taken and send it to the back-end side

Comment: @user7389750 thats what the code in solution does. It passes the image to back-end where you can store in DB or file system. As I have mentioned in my post you can use AJAX/JQuery to send the content of image but I provided you a simpler way to use code-behind.